# Show Read More Link for Truncated Text

Tags: javascript

I have 8 divs with the class of bios_ellipsis with 8 links with the class of read_more. When the browser is made smaller, the clientWidth also becomes smaller and I am using the following css in order to truncate the text:

```
.bios_ellipsis {
vertical-align: middle!important;
overflow: hidden!important;
text-overflow: ellipsis!important;
display: -webkit-box!important;
-webkit-line-clamp: 5!important; 
line-clamp: 5!important;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical!important;
display: -moz-box;
}
```

I want the read more link to appear for every bios_ellipsis div and this link goes to 8 different urls. The problem with the code below is that the read more links end up in different places on top of the divs and don't show up in an orderly manner.

jquery cdn

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        
     var getElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bios_ellipsis');
     
      Array.from(getElements).forEach(function(element) {
      var pos = $('.bios_ellipsis').offset();
      if ( element.clientWidth <= 600 ) {
    
    for(var i = 0; i < getElements.length; i++){
    var top = pos.top[i] + '100px';
    var left = pos.left[i] + '500px';
    
    $('.read_more').css({
      position:'absolute',
      top:top[i],
      left:left[i]
    });
    
    }}
    });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me, without reproducible examples or images, what the actual problem is. What exactly do you want this code to do that it is not exactly doing? Take the time to spell out in detail the actual issue to make it easy for those who might offer help.

Comment: Could you create a minimal reproducible example... Also here's a codepen I created answering a similar question for another user. Do note in this example the line count is 2 you could easily update this example to allow for 5 (as you show above) and adjust the margin top... Then you could render your said 8 paragraphs. https://codepen.io/Trevor-Sharp-the-sans/pen/MWLBwbx Hope this helps a little.

Comment: I made a codepen but the read more link to url doesn't show up at all
https://codepen.io/makamo66/pen/NWJRLyR

Comment: I tried changing the absolute position of the read more link but it still doesn't show up when the browser is made smaller.

Comment: I circumvented the problem by styling the name at the beginning of the div as a link. I added text-decoration: underline to the name because this is a link to the same url as the read more link is. Thus, I don't need the read more link any more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using plain CSS without putting head in Jquery CDN

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
    .bios_ellipsis {
      max-height: calc(1.2em * 1);
      /* Set the maximum height for the equivalent of 5 lines */
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      cursor: pointer;
      /* Add a pointer cursor to indicate interactivity */
    }
    
    .bios_ellipsis:hover {
      max-height: none;
      /* Remove the maximum height on hover */
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <p class="bios_ellipsis">
    Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated,
    and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full
    content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be
    truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to
    show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here.
    It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will
    expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text
    goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.Your long text goes here. It will be truncated, and on hover, it will expand to show the full content.
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ashishkumar but I want the read more link to link to an URL and not text. I made a codepen but the read more link to url doesn't show up at all https://codepen.io/makamo66/pen/NWJRLyR